# How to setup intellij 14 to sign my android app without writing the keys to the build.gradle file?

Tags: android, intellij-idea, gradle

I want to setup intellij 14 to sign my app like it is described here 
[enter link description here](http://developer.android.com/tools/publishing/app-signing.html) but my app is on github and I want to be able to commit the build.gradle file to.

How can I configure gradle to sign it but have the keys somewhere else?

Answer (score 1):

One solution is to put the keys in a `gradle.properties` file in your project root. The values that you put in that properties file turn into global variables in the `build.gradle` script that you can refer to.

So, if you have a `gradle.properties` file with:

```
KEYSTORE=HelloConfig.keystore
KEY_ALIAS=HelloConfig
STORE_PASSWORD=laser.yams.heady.testy
KEY_PASSWORD=fw.stabs.steady.wool
```

you can then have a `build.gradle` with:

```
signingConfigs {
    release {
        storeFile file(KEYSTORE)
        keyAlias KEY_ALIAS
        storePassword STORE_PASSWORD
        keyPassword KEY_PASSWORD
    }
}
```

Use `.gitignore` to block having `gradle.properties` be committed to GitHub, and you are set.